# React Native project not working with android studio

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in react native and i successfully installed react native project using command (react-native init projectname),Now i am connected my android with laptop using USB Cable(trying to connect with virtual device) and using command (react-native run android), But showing me error "Make sure you have an android emulator or device connected",I just want to see output in my android phone,How can i do this ?

Comment: Did you installed ADB ?

Comment: @AnisD: yes but as i said i dont have much knowledge about AVD or android studio

Comment: make sure you have [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) installed, then run command `adb devices` it will show connected devices

Comment: install them and execute adb devices to see if your phone being seen by adb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn of **USB Debugging** on device's **Developer Options**
2. Reconnect the device, using the cable. You should get a popup in your
   phone, asking **Allow USB Debugging on this device**
3. Click **Ok**
4. run `adb devices` . if your device is successful connected, you will get an output like `<yourDeviceNumber> DEVICE` or `<yourDeviceNumber> AUTHORIZED`
5. Then run `react-native run android`
6. if your device is not connected, you will get an output like `<yourDeviceNumber> UNAUTHORIZED`
7. In that case, run `adb -s <yourDeviceNumber> tcp:8081 tcp:8081` an do step 5

Comment: whenever i am using command "adb devices" i am getting error "adb is not recognized as internal or external command"

Comment: It means `adb` is not installed in your pc. you have to install it. if you are using **linux**, simply run `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`.

Follow [https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) for more details for windows and mac installation